# struggling with PHP time range group be id - Start time, End time. Please, help!

Tags: php, sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

Sorry to bother again. I posted this before and got help by the amazing guy called Trix but I think he gave up on me... :(

Problem: I have a list of times with an ID and I want to loop through those time within an ID to get the start times and end times. This is an example:

```
time_id           time_duration

 1       2010-10-15 11:15:00
 1       2010-10-15 11:20:00
 1       2010-10-15 11:25:00
 1       2010-10-15 11:30:00
 2       2010-10-15 11:35:00
 2       2010-10-15 11:40:00
 2       2010-10-15 11:45:00
 2       2010-10-15 11:50:00
 2       2010-10-15 11:55:00
 3       2010-10-15 12:00:00
 3       2010-10-15 12:05:00
 4       2010-10-15 12:10:00
 5       2010-10-15 12:15:00
 5       2010-10-15 12:20:00
 5       2010-10-15 12:25:00
```

So the result of this should echo (notice the duration have been grouped by time_id):

```
 time_id 1: "Start 11:15  -  End 11:30"
 time_id 2: "Start 11:35  -  End 11:55"
 time_id 3: "Start 12:00  -  End 12:05"
 time_id 4: "Start 12:10  -  End 12:10"
 time_id 5: "Start 12:15  -  End 12:25"
```

This is where i got to... Trix and Crozin helped me alot.

```
 $dates = mysql_query("SELECT time_id, time_duration FROM time_table' GROUP BY time_id"); 
 while($raw = mysql_fetch_array($dates)){ 
 $time= $raw['time_duration']; 
 $min_time = min(TIME_FORMAT(time_duration,'%h:%i:%s'));
 }
 echo $min_time;
```

Could you please help me with this. I'm really struggling!!!

Comment: I keep getting annoying error messages and its getting frustrating!! I'm crap with PHP

Comment: Those annoying error messages are there to help you debug the problem. They're especially useful when included in questions asked on SO

Comment: Yes Phil, thanks for your wonderful help... Did you write that to piss me off some more? hahaha lool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$dates = mysql_query("SELECT t.time_id,
                             DATE_FORMAT(MIN(t.time_duration), '%H:%i') AS min_time,
                             DATE_FORMAT(MAX(t.time_duration), '%H:%i') AS max_time
                        FROM TIME_TABLE t
                    GROUP BY t.time_id"); 

while($raw = mysql_fetch_array($dates)) { 
  echo "time_id $raw['time_id']: Start $raw['min_time'] - End $raw['max_time']";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG Ponies has a great suggestion that does almost everything in the sql query.  I don't know if you are inclined to do the logic in PHP because you were unaware/uncomfortable with the more complex SQL, or if you for some reason want to do more of the work in PHP.

Your PHP appears to follow mostly the right idea, but this line has full of problems

$min_time = min(TIME_FORMAT(time_duration,'%h:%i:%s'));

One min with one literal argument?  It needs to be given either an array or two or more literals.
Two: you are using TIME_FORMAT improperly.

> echo TIME_FORMAT('2010-10-15 11:15:00', '%h:%m:%s');  //crashes when i run it

Three: time_duration is an index of $raw, your response row.  It is not an acceptable argument.  Perhaps you meant to put $time there?

I like using UNIX timestamps (long integers that store the year,second, and everything in between) and formatting them right before display, you might find that useful for this purpose.  Check out the functions [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to see what thats about.  It would make your comparisons easy and worry-free, and you can just format it as desired right before (or in) the echo.

Comment: Actually, I don't see TIME_FORMAT in php manual at all.  i think this is just an SQL thing.